# MongoDB Is there a way to find a dataset multiple times based on their child values

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am developing a social calendar application and want to make a feature for recuring events. I decided to use the following schhema as this might be the least memory intense for transfering (using meteorJS)

```
{ 
   title: "Some Title",
   /* ... some other fields for the event, e.g. location, name of venue, decription etc, a lot of data */
   date: new Date(), // JS Date the event takes place first time or date for single event
   repeatMethod: { //Every 2nd Monday in month, is used for generating repeatingEvents array
      type: "monthly"
      day: "Monday"
      value: "2"
   },
   repeatingEvents: [
     {
       date: /*date for the first month */,
       additionalStuff....
     },
     {
       date: /* date for the second month */,
     },
     {
       date: /*Date for the third month */,
       canceled: true
     } 
  ]
}
```

I have several of these events (Around 100 Recuring events that repeat every week and around 50 events that repeat every month) and some single events that have no recurence.

Problem: I need to be able to list all events in a list like this:

```
Event 1 Occurence 1
Event 2 Occurence 1
Event 3 Single Event
Event 1 Occurence 2
Event 2 Occurence 2
Event 3 Occurence 1

...
```

but I want also to be able to limit the start and enddate of this list.

My first approach was to use single datasets per event but that blows up the database extremely. It also would be needed to store a complete event just for marking it canceled.

What way can I effectively find all events in a special timespan and list them ordered by date?

Comment: Just an observation, but if you wanted to alert something on the 5th day of very month then wht not just store `{ "day": 5, "eventdata": "something"}`? Fairly easy to slice up dates and work out that today/next day (whatever)  is the 5th day and simply retrieve that single item. Seems a lot more common sense that repeating the same data over and over again on a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

You're worrying about space when you should be worrying about seek times & user experience. Space is cheap, computations (and definitely user retention) aren't.

I suggest 2 collections, `Events, Occurrences`.

Store the `eventId` on the Occurrence document & index it.

So an event doc has `_id, venue, title, etc.`

An occurrence doc has `_id, eventId, datetime, venue, title, etc.`

Note:

- Occurrence repeats venue because what happens if the regular venue isn't available a particular week? As a user, if changing the venue for 1 week changes the venue for all weeks, I'm gonna be grumpy.
- We also repeat title (and all other fields, except the repetition info) so we don't need to access 2 collections for our queries. Denormalization is healthy, especially in a NoSQL environment.
- This enables the user to change a field (like title) for a particular week (occurrence). If they want to change that field for ALL upcoming weeks, or maybe change the repeat structure, then they edit the event itself & that change to the event doc is propagated to all future occurrences.

A side effect of this structure is a really easy query for what you want: `Occurrences.find({eventId: event, datetime: {$gt: date, $lt: date})`.